# Shell Script: Permission Denied even when the script has builtin mount -o remount, exec

Tags: shell

I am working on a script when executed will take some backups of few files and then replace the original files with the new one. I want if who ever runs this script, even from a dir that has "noexec" set, then the script will remount the dir to "exec". I already have the script in place but somehow even after I am logged in as root I am getting permission denied. Below is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage(){
        echo " "
        echo "TEST_SCRIPT.sh"
        echo "----------------------------------------------------------"
        echo "  usage:"
        echo "          ./TEST_SCRIPT.sh <DIR/PATH/>"
        echo "----------------------------------------------------------"
        echo "use the correct DIRECTORY PATH for the new certs"
        echo " "
        exit 1
}
Implementation(){
        # Check if /tmp/ is mounted with "noexec" option, if it is, then remount it w/ exec.
        tmpMountOpts=$(mount -l | grep -w '/tmp' | awk '{print  $NF}')
        if [[ $tmpMountOpts =~ "noexec" ]]; then
           echo "/tmp/ is mounted with 'noexec' option, remounting..."
           mount -o remount,exec /tmp
           TMP_EXEC=1
        fi
        
         # Defining the variables
         
         # REST of the Script
}
         
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        usage
elif [ ! -d $1 ]
then
        usage
elif [ $# -ne 0 ]
then
    if [ $(ls -A $1 | grep ".*\.pem$" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
    then
       Implementation $1
        else 
        usage
        fi
fi
```

PS: I am able to execute the script if I use "sh TEST_SCRIPT.sh" but if I use "./TEST_SCRIPT.sh" then I only get "permission denied".

Comment: If the script is on a `noexec` device, then it can't be executed. Not even to change the device to `exec` (since the script can't be executed to begin with, it's kind of a catch-22).

Comment: Also, changing mount options implicitly is rather nasty. Since `exec` is usually the default, someone put some effort to make sure that the device is `noexec`. Changing that option could open the system for intrusions and other security problems.

Comment: i am able to execute the script if i use "sh TEST_SCRIPT.sh" but if i use "./TEST_SCRIPT.sh" then only i get "permission denied"

Comment: That should have been part of the original question, as it's a rather crucial detail. And it tells me that you forgot to set the `x` flag on the script (e.g. `chmod ugo+x TEST_SCRIPT.sh`)

Comment: i dont think that is the issue as i am root and the script has 777 priveledge:

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root      3603 Aug 16 18:44 TEST_SCRIPT.sh

i have already done "chmod a+x TEST_SCRIPT.sh"

Comment: Okay, then back to storing the script (or *any* executable program) on a `noexec` device. You simply can't execute such scripts. When you do `sh TEST_SCRIPT.sh` you don't actually execute the script itself, but you execute the command `sh` which only *reads* the script (and then performs its instructions). You just can't invoke (directly execute) any program on a `noexec` device.

Comment: If your script exits non-zero it should emit an error message.  A usage statement is not an error message.   The script should either print a usage statement and exit 0, or print an error message to stderr and exit non-zero. (The latter is preferred.)

Answer (score 0):

If /tmp folder is mounted with network storage device (NFS/NAS/SAN).
Only the storage's administrator may/should modify its execution permissions.

**Better option!**

1. Create your own temp directory with ample storage space.
2. Clear your temp directory (failed or interrupted scripts).
3. Write into your temp directory.
4. Clear your temp directory.